# How to write custom operator for Publisher?

Tags: swift, combine

How to write custom operator for Publisher which would include **compactMap** and **tryMap** operators?
As result I would like to have one method **tryMyMap** which will cover compactMap and tryMap operators.

Below is simplified example what I want to achieve.

```
struct My: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

let json1 = "{ \"value\": 1 }"
let json2 = "{ \"value\": 2 }"

var array = [json1, json2].publisher


array
    .compactMap { Data($0.utf8) }   // 1: Converts String to Data
    .tryMap { try JSONDecoder().decode(My.self, from: $0) } // 2: Decodes data to My class
    .sink { (error) in
        print(error)
    } receiveValue: { (my) in
        print(my)
    }
```

I tried many things. Bellow one of them:

```
extension Publisher {
    func tryMyMap<T>(_ transform: @escaping (My) throws -> T) -> Publishers.TryMap<Self, My> {
        tryMap {
            let d = try transform($0 as! My)
            let dd = My(value: $0)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorscomposed.html

Comment: @matt thanks for article.